# Difference between Ethereum Web APIs and Ethereum API as a service

Tags: blockchain, dapps, infura

I am approaching ethereum for the first time and I am reading the documentation. Can anyone explain the difference between Ethereum Web APIs (BlockCypher) and The Ethereum API as a service (infura)? Https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/backend/#available-libraries